# Apache 2.4 404 Error with Joomla .htaccess

Tags: apache, joomla

I updated to Apache 2.4.  My Joomla sites have not changed and are using the latest versions .. 3.5.8.  My .htaccess file has not changed and I have other sites that are working, just not my Joomla site.  What's different with Apache 2.4 that would cause this problem?

I have searched Joomla's site and there's not mention of Apache 2.4 issues that I can find.  I've also tried changing the .htaccess file but that doesn't make sense since it's delivered by Joomla.

Answer (score 4):

I've had this same issue.  The problem is that Apache 2.4 handles .htaccess files a bit different.  Well, its just the Directives that have changed.  Look at your Apache virtualhost config and update it as follows:

```
<Directory "your directory here">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

With Apache 2.4 the "order" gets deprecated and is replaced by "require",

Comment: Oh, man .... you are a live saver!   That was it.  I'm not sure how you found the answer but I'm a happy camper.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot vote up your answer.  I tried but I do not have enough reputation yet.  Someone else please vote up.  This is a significant change from Apache 2.2.